# What is the difference between fsck and e2fsck?

Tags: linux, fsck

What is the difference between the linux disk error-checking tools fsck and e2fsck?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

fsck is just the original name.  When they came out with new file systems they would need a specific tool for each one, efsck for ext, e2fsck for ext2, dosfsck, fsckvfat.  So they made fsck the front end that just calls whichever is the appropriate tool.

Comment: Hmm, so apparently you can use the fsck "front-end" for some common tasks, but not for everything? For example the -c option (http://superuser.com/questions/20010/fsck-options-for-most-thorough-disk-check/20040#20040) is mentioned in e2fsck man page but in that of fsck.

Comment: Is there a GPT fsck?

Comment: @Jonathan fsck checks filesystems, while GPT is the partition table itself. There's probably a tool that can check those, but I can't think of one off the top of my head other than the Mac's Disk Utility (or the command line diskutil). The `gpt` command does have a "recover from backup table" option, at least on Mac.

Answer (score 19):

**fsck** is a wrapper for the filesystem-specific **fsck.*** family of tools. They can be used interchangeably with one caveat (from the fsck manpage):

> Options  which  are  not  understood
>   by fsck are passed to the
>   filesystem-specific checker.  **These
>   arguments must not   take arguments,
>   as there is no way for fsck to be able
>   to properly guess  which  arguments 
>   take  options  and  which   don’t.**
>
> Options  and  arguments which follow
>   the -- are treated as file
>   system-specific options to be passed
>   to the file system-specific
>   checker.
>
> Please note that fsck is not
>   designed to pass arbitrarily
>   complicated options to 
>   filesystem-specific  checkers.   **If you’re  doing  something complicated,
>   please just execute the
>   filesystem-specific checker directly.** 
>   If you pass fsck   some horribly
>   complicated option and arguments, and
>   it doesn’t do what you expect, don’t
>   bother  reporting  it  as  a   bug. 
>   You’re almost certainly doing
>   something that you shouldn’t be doing
>   with fsck.

However, fsck will handle most of the normal operations on a file system.

Answer (score 8):

On my system I have:

- `fsck`
- `fsck.ext2`
- `fsck.ext3`
- `fsck.ext4`
- `e2fsck`
- ... (more `fsck.*` tools for other, non-ext filesystems)

Now none of these are symbolic links but `e2fsck` and the `fsck.ext2/3/4` tools all share the same inode so are actually the same file. (It is possible that this binary will interrogate its own name when it is run and behave differently for the name it is invoked with, but I doubt this is the case.)

So we're now down to just two tools:

- `fsck`
- `e2fsck`

And, as others have said, `fsck` is simply a front end that calls the appropriate tool for the filesystem in question, which in this case is `e2fsck` for an ext family filesystem.

I presume the reason for having the various `fsck.ext2/3/4` files is so that 1. it's easy to write scripts that can handle all filesystem types generically (they can deduced the fsck tool name trivially from the filesystem type) and 2. for flexibility, so that it's trivial to split the e2fsck into two or more independent tools if necessary in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the longer explanation, because after reading @hyperslug answer I was already sensing heart attack :-) I have ext3 filesystem and I ran e2fsck.

Comment: *Now none of these are symbolic links but e2fsck and the fsck.ext2/3/4 tools all share the same inode so are actually the same file. (It is possible that this binary will interrogate its own name when it is run and behave differently for the name it is invoked with, but I doubt this is the case.)* - Why not - this is a particularly \*nix-ish way of doing things and could actually be the case!

Comment: Those alternate names are actually examples of the lesser-spotted **hard** link (most people are familiar with *symbolic* links but their harder brother also has it uses though they are confined to the same *device*.)